# What's the origin of Seth Meyers' running gag about Mike Lindell ("tha bears!")?

Tags: late-night-with-seth-meyers, seth-meyers

Pretty much every single time Seth Meyers mentions Mike Lindell (often while doing an impression of him) he closes with some variation of the phrase "tha bears!" (at least that's what I'm hearing) in a very specific cadence

Some random examples (links to exact timestamps):

- 
- 
- (slight variation: "cy-bears!")

I often wondered what the origin of this joke was. So far, my research hasn't turned up anything. I should probably mention that I'm not from the US and had never heard about Lindell before he started being mentioned by Late Night talk show hosts, so I guess it might be a riff on a phrase he used in his commercials? Does anybody have a link?

Comment: It's *Da* bears.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's from an Saturday Night Live skit in the early 90s called "Bill Swerski's Super Fans".

An example of the skit:

It features a group of men with very thick Chicago accents who are super fans of the Chicago Bears American football team. They all frequently yell "Da Bears!" whenever they get brought up. Most of the characters sport mustaches similar to Lindell's which makes him look like he belongs to that group.

Comment: Oh, wow, no wonder I didn't make that connection. :D That's quite a stretch. And in hindsight, there was even a hint in the second of the random samples I picked... (totally lost on me, being from Germany and thus not being able to identify (most) US dialects if my life depended on it)...

Comment: and one might add that the mustache joke was alluding to the Bears' coach Mike Ditka, as well as the fact that Myers was an actor on SNL (though much later than these skits)

Comment: Seth of course was a long-time SNL head-writer and cast member before getting his own show, though this was before his time there.  He has, when doing this impression, sometimes apologized since Lindell is from Minnesota, not Chicago.

Comment: "I didn't make that connection" I feel I must congratulate you for that :)

Comment: It's a pretty old sketch (1991), but it was quite famous in it's time and SNL had many sequels to it through 1992.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman To Meyers's credit, Lindell's accent is not too far off from the one used by the characters in the sketch. He doesn't just look like he belongs, he sounds like it.

Comment: @Barmar Oh for sure.  I think the part he's apologizing for is the assumption that Lindell would be a Bears fan rather than the Vikings, I guess?  (I have no idea what if any sports teams he's actually a fan of, but that seems more likely for a Minnesotan.)

Comment: @RBarryYoung It's certainly still in the top 5 most famous SNL sketches

Comment: What's the origin of [Michael] Meyers' running gag? : "Shortly after Robert Smigel moved from New York to Chicago in 1983 to start his career in comedy, he made his first visit to Wrigley Field to see the Cubs play. He noticed **a prevalence of large men who wore walrus mustaches and aviator sunglasses**, a look similar to Mike Ditka, who had been hired to coach the city's NFL team, the Chicago Bears, the year before. "There was just a swagger among these very virile-looking men", he recalled. "All sports fans kind of have it." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_Swerski%27s_Superfans

Comment: @OliverGiesen I suspect that part of the reason it happened was that Seth's attempt at doing a Lindell impression sounded a lot like the voice and accent used in that sketch. And that voice is so unique that other people recognized it as well.

Comment: Could anyone identify the first time that Seth did this (ideally with a YouTube link)? I assume there would have been a little more information around it, then?

Comment: Having never heard of the Seth Myers bit, I knew exactly what the answer would be just from the question.  Unless you were at least a teenager in the early 90s, it's probably hard to image just how thoroughly this sketch embedded itself into popular culture.  My first thought when I saw the title was, "Man he spelled it wrong."  Then I heard the correct spelling in my head, 'da Bearz'.

Comment: @OliverGiesen: I wasn't familiar with the original SNL sketch either when I noticed Seth repeating this joke a while ago.  But I assumed Seth was probably referencing *something*.  So I googled "da bears" and got the answer.  (And I knew Seth's history with SNL so that made sense.)  As a native speaker, I probably had an easier time hearing exactly how he was saying it and coming up with the same phonetic spelling that the Internet recognizes.